# Is PHP memory-inefficient at string manipulating?

Tags: php

Today I had an issue today with PHP and MySQL ([here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348615/insert-value-with-dot-in-mysql?)), which has already been solved but it awakened a new, more theorical, question.

The thing is that in MySQL database I had a field whose type was `VARCHAR(64)`. When trying to insert a string from a php script, the full string was more than 64 bytes, making a `var_dump` proved it had 71. BUT, here is what I do not understand, running the exact same query, with the exact same string, but manually from phpmyadmin, it did fit in the 64-byte sql field.

So, here is the question. **Is there any reason of why the same string in php takes more memory than inserting it directly to the database?**

EDIT: Someone suggested a duplicate of a charset-related question. The charset in MySQL is utf8_general_ci. In PHP I have not defined the charset, but if I di `print(mb_detect_encoding($string));` I get it is ASCII encoded. May this be the reason? How wrong can I be if I think ASCII takes less memory than utf8? (Anyways, in the script I have `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");` so it should be converted to utf8 before querying)

Comment: Are you sure PHPMyAdmin inserted the whole string and didn't just truncate a part of it (as it did when I just tried it)?

Comment: don't confuse bytes with characters. a unicode string can have 64 "characters", but require many more bytes than 64.

Comment: @kingkero chk link that OP mentioned in question

Comment: When I copy the URL in the previous question it has a hidden character in it which returns `string(65) "http://example.com/upload/news_img/1455220595Untitled-1‌​.jpg"` Removing the hidden character reduces the string length to 62.